# ttkbootstrap got an unexpected keyword argument 'themes_file' , why?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttkbootstrap

I always used this as part of my tkinter app without any issues:

```
# STYLE settings
themefile = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
s = Style(theme="finaltb", themes_file=f"{themefile}\\tbtheme.json")

s.configure("TEntry", relief="flat", borderwidth=1)
s.configure("TCombobox", relief="flat", borderwidth=1)

app = s.master
app.title("bla")
width = app.winfo_screenwidth()
height = app.winfo_screenheight()
app.geometry("1000x850")
app.minsize(1000, 850)
app.iconbitmap("logo5.ico")
```

After letting my program untouched for around 6 month now I get this error message when I try to run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "....GUI.py", line 76, in <module>
s = Style(theme="finaltb", themes_file=f"{themefile}\\tbtheme.json")        

TypeError: Style.__new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'themes_file'
```

Comment: In the [doc](https://ttkbootstrap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/style/style) I don't see any mention of `themes_file` as a keyword arg. You might want to use the method [load_user_themes](https://ttkbootstrap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/style/style/#ttkbootstrap.style.Style.load_user_themes)